# How to convert html website to wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

i want to convert my html website to the wordpress. But can you please talk me that how i can convert and connect the other pages with the main page???

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start from the point of view you already have Wordpress and are ready to start.

You can't take your existing HTML website and just add it to WP.

What you need to do is to build your own custom theme, that matches your current HTML files, using the already existing WP templates and files.

Best way is to duplicate an existing theme to play/manipulate so that you don't break WP. The last thing you want to do, having no experience, is to mess with and break the default theme and be unable to get it back again without a full re-install.

RE 'connect the other pages with the main page' WP allows you to have static pages and set them as your home page and/or anywhere else you want. With these pages you can also set up different templates within your theme if you need to.

Wordpress have all this help available here:
[Wordpress creating static pages and custom templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Theme_Development_for_Custom_Front_Page_Templates)

Comment: I already convert psd to html but i want wordPress theme....is it difficult to convert html website to wordpress theme??? i have only basic knowledge about the worpresss, and am using wamp server

Comment: I guess then, the next best thing is to take your HTML website code and put it side by side with an existing theme so you can see what tags you need and where you need replace/place them in your code.

I'd also expect you will need to break up your original code into the many includes you will need, minimum the header and footer parts plus many others.

Once you have done all that, then I guess its a simple case of creating your custom theme from the files you now have.

Personally, I'd go the original way I mentioned but both ways solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really that simple. You should read about WP theming. Here's the start:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Check codes from other themes to see how to output basics. Theming has a lot of parts, but to ouput custom html you will need these files:

- style.css
- functions.php
- index.php
- single.php

With those you should have an basic blog output with core WP functionality.